# getMapAsync of onMapReadyCallback MapBoxSDK Returns NULL map for very First time run Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using MapBox SDK MAP 
**When I install my app for Very First Time** 
The method: **onMapReady** of **mapView.getMapAsync** Returns **NULL**

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        Here mapboxMap = NULL   <---   What To Do Here???
        ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide more information including your entire activity? Your mapview might still be null. For a complete, working example, reference the Mapbox documentation: mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear about your problem with `getMapAsync`. If you're seeing a `mapboxMap` `null` object that's a bug. Please submit a bug report via [the issue tracker](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/new) so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you called onCreate() on mapView before calling getMapAsync()?

I faced same exception.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Problem was resolved on adding 2nd statement for onCreate()

Comment: Thanks, this must be the valid answer, now its running